# ArgumentException Message displayed in a Label

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, argumentexception

```
    public void DeleteUser(User user)
    {
        if (!UserExists(user))
            throw new ArgumentException("User doesn't exist!");
        else
        {
            MatrixDb.Users.Remove(user);
            MatrixDb.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I want to show that "ArgumentException" message in a proper way on the page; I want it inside the ValidationSummary Helper or a Label, so that when the User faces it, they are not sent to '**Server Error in '/' Application**' Page rather, the error is shown in some Controller, like a Label or Textfield.

Is this even possible?! Because on the Server Page that's shown when the ArgumentException is raised, does show that message there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(User user)
    {

        try
        {
            Delete(user);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewData["error"] = e.Message; //ViewBag.error = e.Message can be used too        
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@if (ViewData["error"] != null) //ViewBag.error != null  
{
   <h2>@ViewData["error"].ToString()</h2> //@ViewBag.error.ToString() if ViewBag is used
}
```